# UK bank sort code javascript reg. expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to validate one of two sort codes. I have already created the below expression to match one of the sort codes but unsure how I would match a second sort code as part of the same expression. The below REGEX should match any sort code beginning with `72` but how would I add an expression that it should match either of `72` plus `04`? Any help would be appreciated.

```
^[7]{1}[2]{1}[0-9]{4}$
```

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 0):

You could actually rewrite your current regex as:

```
^72[0-9]{4}$
```

And to make it also match 6 digit numbers beginning with `04`, you can use the OR operator `|` and a non-capture group:

```
^(?:72|04)[0-9]{4}$
```

`(?: ... )` is the non-capture group, which will limit the scope of the OR to only `72` and `04`.

Some sample numbers it matches:

```
721234
041234
```